# Name of a "normalized" second moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation, terminology

I am asking myself how this second moment would be referred to in English:

$$ \frac{E(X^2)} {(EX)^2} $$

I would have called it standardized for instance, but for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_moment) refers to standardized moments as something different. Sorry, not a native speaker...

Comment: [Wikipedia also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Similar_ratios) $\frac{E(X^2)} {(EX)^2}-1 =\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2}$ is sometimes called the efficiency

Comment: What do you do if $E(X)=0$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson let's rule that case out